# RHEL RPM spec post installation %post not sourcing shell script

Tags: shell, rhel, rpm-spec

I am trying to **source** a shell script in the root environment (as I am doing installation as root) after successful installation of a rpm in RHEL7.4 box

The rpm spec **%post** section is as follows:

```
%post
source /etc/profile.d/env.sh
```

script **env.sh** is available after installation in the mentioned path and it is used to set **PYTHONPATH** environment variable like this:

```
pypath="/opt/lib"
if [ "$(echo $PYTHONPATH | grep $pypath)" == "" ]; then
        export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$pypath"
fi
```

However, it is not happening after successful rpm installation even if I change the "**source**" command to "**.**" script

When I source the script **env.sh** manually then the variable is set

Comment: Is nothing happening? Or are you getting an error? What does  your complete `%post` section look like? What does `/etc/profile.d/env.sh` look like?

Comment: `%post` looks the same as I given here

Comment: How are you determining that `PYTHONPATH` is not set correctly? If `%post` looks the same as what you've posted here, you're not actually using Python in your `%post` script, so setting `PYTHONPATH` in that environment wouldn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably the command is running correctly, but you expect the PYTHONPATH to be changed for everybody; which is not the case: the PYTHONPATH is only changed for the shell session of the %post section.

Each time you start a new shell (or bash) session, your environment variables are reset. You can take a look to related questions for information on how to change environment variables permanently; then you can choose which strategy to use for your rpm package, for example:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: This is the problem. Your RPM should be dropping a file in `/etc/profile.d` and then the user needs to re-login to get it. **Don't** have your `%post` edit `/etc/bash_profile` or anything like that; if you find advice telling you to do that, it is _ancient_ and _wrong_.

Comment: So each `%section` of spec file runs in its own shell session

Comment: yes, but even if they ran in your current session that wouldn't help you, since opening a new session would still reset your environment variables.